# Xcode Quick Look Documentation not showing up if from different framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on an SDK and I wanted to document methods like this:

```
/**
Does something

- Version:
1.0
*/

func doSomething() {
}
```

However, when I use the method from a sample app, this documentation doesn't show up in Quick Look. If I document a method that's declared in the app itself, then it works as expected. How do I document my framework methods?

Comment: 1. What is the Xcode version? 2. Was the SDK created on the same Xcode version, on which you are trying the app?

Comment: I'm using 10.1 right now, though much of the development was done in 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I realized the quick look documentation showed up after I restarted Xcode, which led me to realize that all I needed to do was clean my project after I added new documentation.